# Request for member [...] in [...], which is of non-class type [...]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've searched in the internet for solutions to this compiling error. Most of them seem to have to do with two options:

- Treating a pointer as an object and not dereferencing it.
- Mistaking a variable with a function returning the variable type and trying to access it.

My code is:

```
#ifndef ESCRITOR_PROLOG_HH
#define ESCRITOR_PROLOG_HH

#include "planning.hh"
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

class EscritorProlog {
private:
  Planning planningAEscriure;
public:
  EscritorProlog(Planning planning);
  EscritorProlog(Planning &&planning);
  void escriuFitxerProlog(std::ostream &escritor);
};

#endif
```

And the main.cc:

```
#ifndef MAIN_CC
#define MAIN_CC

#include "escritorProlog.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main () {
  std::ofstream escritor("./test.txt");
  EscritorProlog test(Planning());
  test.escriuFitxerProlog(escritor);
}
#endif
```

If you try to compile it with

```
g++ -c main.cc -std=c++11
```

You'll just get the error...

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:11:8: error: request for member ‘escriuFitxerProlog’ in ‘test’, which is of non-class type ‘EscritorProlog(Planning (*)())’
   test.escriuFitxerProlog(escritor);
```

Now I don't know if I'm missing something but I can't see any of the two issues mentioned before in my code. I'm sorry if I'm blatantly blind or anything but I just don't see the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have declared a function taking one parameter of pointer to function type my friend. Why do you think you can apply the dot operator to a function?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I thought I was simply declaring an object lol. C++ is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an instance of [**the most vexing parse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You can fix it by using *list-initialization*, which is unambiguous in this context:

```
EscritorProlog test(Planning{});
```

Unfortunately you have ambiguous `EscritorProlog` construction from `Planning`:

```
EscritorProlog(Planning planning); // (1)
EscritorProlog(Planning &&planning); // (2)
```

Assuming that you wanted to define a *copy-constructor* for `(1)`, change the signature to

```
EscritorProlog(const Planning& planning);
```

in order to avoid ambiguity. With these changes, your code will compile.

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dDJA448yRyKZSM3B)

Comment: Alright, thank you!